# Recycler View Item not changing its colour

Tags: java, android, colors, onclick, android-recyclerview

I had a recycler view and a grid layout manager to that.For the layout item inflated for recycler view I set a background colour like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/regNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="@drawable/student_li_bgcolor"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="15BEC0584"
        android:textColor="#64DD17"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The content of student_li_bgcolor is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#64DD17"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ffffff"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ffffff"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

What I want to acheive is changing the item color to green if user has pressed it atleast once.

With this code

```
 <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ffffff"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ffffff"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

I'm able to change background colour on click.But its reverting back to its original colour as soon as user removed finger on it.I dont want that.Please help me...Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the background color permanently, you should add an `OnClickListener` and do it in `OnClickListener.onClick()`.

`<selector>` is just a state list resource that changes appearance depending on the button's current state.

How to use an `onClickListener` please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html).

I'm glad if it can help.

Comment: I've already tried using view.setBackground(Color.parseColor("#000000")) where view is what we get at recyclerview viewHolder one

Comment: But its of no use to me

Comment: Can you show your code of onClickListener() so that I can have a try and give you some feedback.